# Transferring Macro Script - Excel to Google Sheet (SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (line 1, file)

Tags: html, excel, vba

Having a bit of an issue, tried just pasting the same macro script from excel into GSheets Recorded Macros and it's not having it. Basically I have a button where I enter the information, click and it adds a new line on the front page of a new MDA (initials of person). There is also one to remove.

```vb
Sub New_MDA()
'Add New MDA Macro
    Dim a As Integer, ValueToFind As String
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Call Unprotect_Password
     Sheets("MDA's").Rows("2:4").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    'Check MDA is entered
    If Sheets("Insert New Staff").Range("E8").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("No MDA Entered")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check First Name is entered
    If Sheets("Insert New Staff").Range("E9").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("No First Name Entered")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check Surname is entered
    If Sheets("Insert New Staff").Range("E10").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("No Surname Entered")
        Exit Sub
    End If


    'See if MDA already exits in table
    LastRow = Sheets("MDA's").Cells(Sheets("MDA's").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ValueToFind = Sheets("Insert New Staff").Range("E8").Value
    For a = 2 To LastRow
       If Sheets("MDA's").Cells(a, 2).Value = ValueToFind Then
           MsgBox ("The MDA " & ValueToFind & " already exists on row " & a)
           Range("A1").Select
           Exit Sub
       End If
     Next a

    'Insert new line
    Sheets("MDA's").Rows("4:4").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    'Add MDA
    Sheets("MDA's").Range("B4").Value = Sheets("Insert New Staff").Range("E8").Value

    'Add First Name
    Sheets("MDA's").Range("C4").Value = Sheets("Insert New Staff").Range("E9").Value

    'Add Surname
    Sheets("MDA's").Range("D4").Value = Sheets("Insert New Staff").Range("E10").Value

    'Fill full name formula
    Sheets("MDA's").Range("E4").Value = "=LEFT(C4,1)&"" ""&D4"

    'Sort
    Sheets("MDA's").Select
    Range("B2:E" & LastRow + 1).sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Header:=xlYes

    Sheets("MDA's").Range("A1").Select

    Call Update_MDA_DropDownBox

    'Delete Old Info
    Sheets("Insert New Staff").Range("E8:E10").ClearContents
    Sheets("Insert New Staff").Select
    Range("A1").Select

 Sheets("MDA's").Rows("3:4").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Call Add_Password

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add your issue/error.

Comment: Gsheets uses JavaScript, Excel uses VBA... So you can't copy paste.

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets and Excel are 2 completely different applications.

Google Sheets uses *Google Apps Script* (a kind of JavaScript) as language and Excel uses *VBA* as language. So you would need to translate the code yourself from VBA into Google Apps Script as there is no automatic translation for that.

Actually it is re-writing the entire code in another language.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am such a noob when it comes to script.. :)